# Why is programmatic click not working on IE or Chrome?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm using this bookmarklet to programmatically click on the search button in [Google's Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal):

```
javascript:document.getElementById("gwt-debug-searchPanel-searchButton").click();
```

I also tried this in IE with no luck:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("gwt-debug-searchPanel-searchButton").fireEvent("onclick");
```

It actually worked once but then it didn't work anymore. It works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome or IE. Any idea why?

Comment: I'd imagine it's a security setting, since programmatic clicks can't have their intent (malicious/innocent) assessed by the end-user or browser. And, personally, it's one I agree with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That button is likely going to submit a form, why not submit the form with Javascript? You are always allowed to do that.

Comment: Then maybe fetch the onclick event and execute it? Like `javascript:document.getElementById("gwt-debug-searchPanel-searchButton").onclick()` I don't know if that works. It will only execute any JavaScript that is behind the button, it wont actually 'click' the button.

Comment: A weird thing is that if I use this http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event and trigger the click event it works. So that tool is somehow performing the right programmatic click.

Comment: What you're trying to do might not be possible because you can functions in JavaScript by hiding the scope. I think you'll have to figure out what the button does and pray you can call it from your global scope.

Comment: Well, Visual Event is somehow doing it.